# jwtInterceptorProvider.tokenGetter not append token to header

Tags: angularjs, jwt, angular-services, json-web-token

I am trying to use angular-jwt in `service` but it does not append authorization on http call:

```
angular.module('TestApp')
  .config(function Config($httpProvider, jwtInterceptorProvider) {
    jwtInterceptorProvider.tokenGetter = ['merchantService', function(merchantService) {
        merchantService.doSomething();
        return localStorage.getItem('token');
    }];

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('jwtInterceptor');
  })
  .service('Merchant', ['$http', function($http) {
    var baseUrl = "http://test.com";

    return {
        terminal: function(success, error) {
            $http.jsonp(baseUrl + '/tests?callback=jsonp_callback').success(success).error(error)
        }
    } 
  }]);
```

Comment: there is no way unless localStorage return nothing... Please write test string to check if your localStorage working...

Comment: Token is in the locaStorage, but it is no Authorization append in the header.

Comment: code seems fine probably there is something wrong with your service or localStorage again. Just remove them for testing and just return sample string and look if it will be added on header...

Comment: Did this: var token = '...'; return token;, no luck

Comment: jwtInterceptorProvider.tokenGetter = ['store', function (store) {
            return store.get('jwt');
        }];
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('jwtInterceptor'); this is my code which is same with you and working...

Comment: maybe you forgot to inject localStorage, try inject localStorage into tokenGetter

Comment: @Alvin did you find a solution for this? I'm having the same issue...